# Azure Active Directory add exception for AD application from "Security Defaults"

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, azureportal

There is a option in AD to enable or disable "Security Defaults".

```
AD Portal > Dashboard > AD Tenant >  Properties > Manage Security Defaults > Enable security defaults
```

Is there a way to exclude a AD user or App from the security defaults?

Comment: I think it can't be realized by ms [graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/identitysecuritydefaultsenforcementpolicy-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: My question was if we can exclude Azure AD Application or a User from the Security Defaults Policy using the Azure Portal.

Comment: I saw the ms graph api tag in your question so I checked in that aspect. sorry sir.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have updated the tags.

Comment: And about your previous question, I have several ideas. Firstly, you used `grant_type: "password"` which means you are using [ropc flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc#authorization-request) and this flow seems to don't have a `response_type` parameter, you may remove this parameter. By the way, this flow is not a recommending flow to get access token. You may using [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) instead

Comment: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=azure_ad_client_id&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:8080%2F&response_mode=query&scope=user.read&state=12345` using this link(don't forget to modify the parameters) to get the auth code in the response url after you sign in, then send post request like this to get access token https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC993.png

Comment: could you pls take a try for it?

Comment: If using auth code flow still didn't work for you then I have no other ideas on it... Pls kindly let me know the result. Thank you in advance sir.

Comment: Could you pls share your test result sir? Thanks in advance

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't want to have user interaction so I can not use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Answer (score 0):

[Security defaults in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults#require-all-users-to-register-for-azure-ad-multi-factor-authentication) is enabled for all users and cannot be disabled on a per user or application basis.

In order to achieve the latter, you will need to implement [Conditional Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/overview).